# Max-height: 0 not collapsing Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like my chat box to collapse when they touch the header of the chat, similar to facebook. I know that hide_wrapBox is correctly being added, but it doesn't set the height of its contained elements to a (collapsed) fixed height. In other words, the messages inside the chat box 
disappear but the box still stands, where I'd prefer it to minimize.

```
     <div id="messages-card-container" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-grid">

      <!-- Messages container -->
      <div id="messages-card" style="display:none;" class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--6-col-desktop">
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--grey-600">

          <div id="convoHeader">HEADER</div>
          <div class="wrapBox">
          <div id="messages">
            <span id="message-filler"></span>
          </div>
          <form id="message-form" action="#">
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
              <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="message" placeholder="Type a message...">
            </div>
          </form>
          <form id="image-form" action="#">
            <input id="mediaCapture" type="file" accept="image/*,capture=camera">
            <button id="submitImage" title="Add an image" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--amber-400 mdl-color-text--white">
            </button>
          </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="must-signin-snackbar" class="mdl-js-snackbar mdl-snackbar">
        <div class="mdl-snackbar__text"></div>
        <button class="mdl-snackbar__action" type="button"></button>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
    $('#convoHeader').click(function(){
    if($('.wrapBox').is(":visible")){
        $('.wrapBox').hide();
        $('#messages').addClass('hide_wrapBox');
        console.log('you get here');
    }else{
        $('.wrapBox').show();
        $('#messages').removeClass('hide_wrapBox');
    }
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
 .hide_wrapBox {
       max-height: 0;
        width: 5px;
        bottom:0;
        outline: 4px solid red;
    }

#messages-card {
  float: right;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  bottom: 0%;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#messages-card-container {
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 400px;
  bottom: 0%;
}
.mdl-layout__header-row span {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 17px;
}
.mdl-grid {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: auto;
}
.material-icons {
  font-size: 36px;
  top: 8px;
  position: relative;
}
.mdl-layout__header-row {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.mdl-card__supporting-text {
  position:relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #888888;
}

#convoHeader, innerHTML{
    position: relative;
    color: white;
}

#convoHeader{
   position:relative;
   background-color: #c4d8e2;
   padding-bottom: 6px;
}

#convoHeader: hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
#messages {
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 270px;
  //outline: 2px solid red;
}
#message-filler {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.message-container:first-of-type {
  border-top-width: 0;
}
.message-container {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  padding-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.message-container.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
.message-container .pic {
  background-image: url('/images/profile_placeholder.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.message-container .spacing {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.message-container .message {
  display: table-cell;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
  color: #666666;
}
.message-container .name {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 40px;
  color: #bbb;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#message-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  float: left;
}
#image-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 48px;
  float: right;
}
#message-form .mdl-textfield {
  //width: 300px;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
}
#message-form, input{
   width:295px;
   height:32px;
   font-size: 12px;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
}
#message-form button, #image-form button {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 15px 0 0 10px;
}
.mdl-card {
  min-height: 0;
}
.mdl-card {
  background: linear-gradient(white, #f9f9f9);
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#user-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  top: 22px;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#user-container #user-pic {
  top: -3px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('/images/profile_placeholder.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-size: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#user-container #user-name {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#image-form #submitImage {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 6px 0 1px;
  min-width: 0;
}
#image-form #submitImage .material-icons {
  top: -1px;
}
.message img {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 200px;
}
#mediaCapture {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 610px) {
  header {
    height: 113px;
    padding-bottom: 80px !important;
  }
  #user-container {
    top: 72px;
    background-color: rgb(3,155,229);
    height: 38px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right: 2px;
  }
  #user-container #user-pic {
    top: 2px;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
    background-size: 33px;
  }
}
.mdl-textfield__label:after {
  background-color: #0288D1;
}
.mdl-textfield--floating-label.is-focused .mdl-textfield__label {
  color: #0288D1;
}
.mdl-button .material-icons {
  top: -1px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually collapsing, but you have the wrapper around those divs such as #messages-card which is setting a height. So while #messages is collapsing, parent of #messages-card is maintaining the height you have set, making it appear nothing is collapsing:

```
#messages-card {
  float: right;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  bottom: 0%;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

You'll need to play around with adjusting that wrapper's height, and it's positioning to resolve the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding hide_wrapBox to messages try toggling it on wrapBox

```
$('#convoHeader').click(function(){
 if($('.wrapBox').is(":visible")){
     $('.wrapBox').addClass('hide_wrapBox');
 }else{
     $('.wrapBox').removeClass('hide_wrapBox');
 } 
});
```